# ideone doesn't show any output

Tags: c++

this code is of problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/BASE/ and it runs fine on windows and linux but when i run it on ideone it does not show me any output. Can anyone tell me what is the reason behind this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

long int convert_base10(char *num, int base)
{
int len, dig;
long int result = 0;
len = strlen(num);
//    printf("len = %d\n", len);
// converting to base 10
for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    if((num[len-i-1] >= 'A') && (num[len-i-1] <= 'F'))
        dig = num[len-i-1] - 55;
    else
        dig = num[len-i-1] - 48;
    result +=  (dig * pow(base, i));
  //        printf("num[%d] = %d\n", len-i-1, dig);
}
return result;
}

void convert_basei(long int num, int base, string &result1)
{
bool error = false;
int pos = 6;
char result[7], rem;
// initially storing space on all position
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    result[i] = ' ';
while(num)
{
    if((num % base) >= 10)
        rem = (num % base) + 55;
    else
        rem = (num % base) + 48;
    result[pos] = rem;//printf("result[%d] = %c\n", pos, rem);
    num /= base;//    printf("quotient = %d\n", num);
    pos--;
    if(pos < 0 && num > 0)
    {
        error = true;
        break;
    }

}
if(error == true)
   result1 = "  ERROR";
else
    result1 = result;
//    cout<<"result = "<<result1<<endl;
}

int main()
{
char num[7];
string result;
int base1, base2;
while(scanf("%s%d%d", num, &base1, &base2) == 3)
{
//        printf("num = %s\nbase1 = %d\nbase2 = %d\n", num, base1, base2);
    long int temp = convert_base10(num, base1);
//        printf("temp = %ld\n", temp);
    convert_basei(temp, base2, result);
    cout<<result<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you ran it on ideone, what input did you feed it? If it doesn't get any input, it won't produce any output.

Comment: What was your ***expected*** output?

Comment: the input is :
1111000  2 10
and the expected output is :
120

Answer (score 3):

Replace this code:

```
while(scanf("%s%d%d", num, &base1, &base2) == 3)
{
    long int temp = convert_base10(num, base1);
    convert_basei(temp, base2, result);
    cout<<result<<endl;
}
```

With this code, and the mystery will go away:

```
printf("trying to get input\n");
while(scanf("%s%d%d", num, &base1, &base2) == 3)
{
    printf("got some input\n");
    long int temp = convert_base10(num, base1);
    convert_basei(temp, base2, result);
    cout<<result<<endl;
}
printf("got no input\n");
```

Comment: Or, perhaps, `while (std::cin >> num >> base1 >> base2)`, since this is [tag:c++]...

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I want to help him understand what his current code is doing and why. Changing it more than needed would make it harder for him to understand what's going on with his original code.

Comment: it still does not print any thing. neither of the printf line goes on the output screen!!!
the ideone link of my code is http://ideone.com/3wJa0i

Comment: @VijayJain: Thanks for the link. I've added an answer based upon it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It really didn't at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a bug at `ideone.com`.

[I cloned your source and input, with a couple of minor adjustments and see no output at all.](http://ideone.com/Q8Kv9m) Since I expected to see some output, I've filed a report using the "report bug / make suggestion" link on the page.

[Then I cloned it again, made a few more stylistic changes and it gives the desired results.](http://ideone.com/G9GZLT)

---

#### Response from Ideone

```
Date: Fri, 8 Mar 2013 12:18:49 +0100
From: Filip Wielewski <wiele@s...>
To: paj-ideone@j...
Cc: contact@i...
Subject: Re: Please see this question on StackOverflow for an explanation...

Hi [Johnsyweb],

thank you for letting us know about this issue. There is indeed
some problem with the original source code posted by Vijay Jain.
We will examine it and try to fix it very soon.

Regards,
Filip Wielewski
Ideone Team

2013/2/16 Ideone bug/suggestion <noreply@i...>

    Ideone bug/suggestion

    category: compiler/interpreter
    type: bug
    date: 2013-02-16 08:38:16
    user: johnsyweb
    e-mail: paj-ideone@j...
    site: http://ideone.com/Q8Kv9m
    compiler: C++ (ver: gcc-4.7.2, id: 1)
    description: Please see this question on StackOverflow for
    an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14907730/78845

    My response:
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/14908061/78845

    Regards;


    --paj
```

Comment: thanks it runs correctly by this but still i didn't get the problem with ideone. May be it is because of some operations between char and string

Comment: @VijayJain: I can't explain the difference either, like I said, I think it's a bug and I reported it.